# AVR compile error - poisoned signal

Tags: avr

I have this code from 2002. I had to update the macros but I still get 'poisoned' error messages from the compiler (AVR Cross Compile, MAC OS X) in Eclipse:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_2WIRE_SERIAL"  test        line 533, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h C/C++ Problem
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_ADC"   test        line 470, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h C/C++ Problem
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_COMPARATOR"    test        line 480, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h C/C++ Problem
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_EEPROM_READY"  test        line 475, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h C/C++ Problem
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_INPUT_CAPTURE1"    test        line 417, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h C/C++ Problem
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_INTERRUPT0"    test        line 367, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h C/C++ Problem
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_INTERRUPT1"    test        line 372, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h C/C++ Problem
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_INTERRUPT2"    test        line 377, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h C/C++ Problem
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_OUTPUT_COMPARE0"   test        line 437, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h C/C++ Problem
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_OUTPUT_COMPARE1A"  test        line 422, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h C/C++ Problem
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_OUTPUT_COMPARE1B"  test        line 427, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h C/C++ Problem
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_OUTPUT_COMPARE2"   test        line 407, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h 
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_OVERFLOW0" test        line 442, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h 
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_OVERFLOW1" test        line 432, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h 
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_OVERFLOW2" test        line 412, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h 
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_SPI"   test        line 447, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h 
attempt to use poisoned "SIG_SPM_READY" test        line 539, external location: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iom128.h
```

Here's the full code (Atmel128):

http://pastebin.com/uAnb2R0v

As far as I know, the SIG_ prefix means these are interrupt vectors. While there aren't interrupts in the code, it still complains. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know what the error message means?

Comment: Yes, it has to do with old, deprecated way of using interrupts. The code does not use any interrupts, hence my confusion.

Comment: It is much easier to just redefine them to their equivalents in the new compiler.

Comment: But there aren't interrupts in the code.

Comment: What command are you using to compile? are the any other source files or .o files lying around?

Comment: You should *not* have `#include <avr/iom128.h>` in your code. This is included by `#include <avr/io.h>`.

Comment: (note the comment at the top of `iom128.h` -> `/* This file should only be included from <avr/io.h>, never directly. */`)

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Arduino#Problem_with_deprecated_items_in_avr-libc_v1.8.0_and_above_.28and_Mega_2560.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what command you are using to compile, but I can't replicate the poisoned signal errors.

However in order to get it to compile with avr-gcc, the following changes have to be made:

1. Replace the 8 occurrences of `__elpm_inline` with `pgm_read_byte_far`. Alternatively you could add `#define __elpm_inline(x) pgm_read_byte_far(x)` to the top of the code, though that is ugly.
2. Replace your weird use of the address macros as functions. For example you do `DDRA(0<<DDA3)`. That should instead be `DDRA &= ~(1<<DDA3)` and so forth.
3. Remove the `#include <avr/iom128.h>` statement. Though that doesn't stop it compiling, it shouldn't be there.

After that it compiles fine using `avr-gcc` with flags of `-mmcu=atmega128` and `-DF_CPU=...`.

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten that before with old code. You are using old deprecated name for the interrupt signal for example the one for the ADC has changed to ADC_vect. Look where the old SIG_ names are define and you'll find the updated names for the interrupt vector names in that .h file

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the code does not use any interrupts. In fact, the offending lines are array data stored in the ROM. Mysterious!